# What is the parametrisation of $x^2-y^2+z^2=0$

Tags: surface-integrals, parametrization

I need to be able to parametrise the surface $x^2-y^2+z^2=0$. I know it can be written as a cone in the form $y=\sqrt{x^2+z^2}$, but I don't know how to parametrise it and would appreciate any explanation of how you do it as well as a solution.

Comment: Hint: start by projecting $y^2=z^2+x^2$ onto the $y$-plane.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite as $$x^2+z^2=y^2$$ and notice that for a fixed value of $y$, you get the equation of a circle centered at $(0,0)$ (in the $xz$-plane) and with radius $|y|$. Let $y=r$ be a first parameter and then from the standard parametrization of a circle:
$$\left\{ 
\begin{array}{rcl}
x & = &  r\cos t \\
y & = &  r \\
z & = &  r\sin t
\end{array}
\right.$$where $0 \le t \le 2\pi$ and $0 \le r < +\infty$ for a single cone, $-\infty < r < +\infty$ for the double cone.

Remark: since parametrizations aren't unique, there is no such thing as ***the*** parametrization, but rather ***a*** parametrization.